# SqlCommand INSERT INTO query does not execute

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, insert

Hello guys I have got this code:

```
SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(
                                "INSERT INTO klient(name,surname) 
                                values(@kname,@ksurname)", 
                                conn);

scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kname", kname.Text);
scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ksurname", ksurname.Text);
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM klient", spojeni);
SDA.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
```

It should insert data from textboxes: kname, ksurname, but it closes the form without showing them in MS SQL table klient

Comment: You simply haven't executed `prikaz`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing the ExecuteNonQuery call

```
SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO klient(name,surname) values(@kname,@ksurname)", spojeni);

prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kname", kname.Text);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ksurname", ksurname.Text);
spojeni.Open();
prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
......
```

A command should be executed to update the database...

Answer (score 3):

You haven't executed the command.

```
prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

The above stated problem is due to the missing executenonquery() statement, add this statement in your code

```
spojeni.Open();
prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
```