# SqlCommand INSERT query does not insert data into the database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, sqlcommand

I am working on [Visual Studio 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2013).

In the below code the `MessageBox.Show("Connected to database")` is shown correctly, but the SQL query is not inserting data into the database table.

When I insert data manually then it inserts without any problems. But unfortunately the data fails to insert on the `button_click` command.

```
private void DataAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=Pathname;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        conn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected to database");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO datains (name, dob, gender, occupation, height, weight, relation, polexpo) values('abc', '22-Aug-2001', 'Male', 'qwe2', '23', '431', 'qw23e', 'asqwed');", conn);
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection failed");
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong here or anything I have missed?

Comment: Is DataAdd_Load called? Do you get any exception?, you did not close the connection which you must.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlCommand INSERT INTO query does not execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569051/sqlcommand-insert-into-query-does-not-execute)

Comment: @Adil it was my silly mistake of not writing the cmd.ExecuteNonquery , wondering for hours and finally stack overflow helped!. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgotten to execute the query:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is also better to close the connection after the work is done:

```
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the ExecuteNonQuery() method of your cmd to make it work, but it's also advisable to wrap both connection and command into a using statement so that they will be disposed (the connection should be also explicitly closed)