# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 's'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

Would you please tell me where is my mistake ?!?
I cannot find any incorrect syntax near any 's' !.
Here is my Code :

```
public static DataTable InsertConnect(ComboBox Site , ComboBox server , ComboBox Host , ComboBox Domain , Label Price)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = Server.Connection;
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblPrice(Site,Server,Host,Domain,Price) 
      values('" + Site.Text + "','" + server.Text + "','" + Host.Text + "','" + Domain.Text + "','" + Price.Text + "')'"; 


    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `'` after your last parentheses?

Comment: I would really suggest to use parameter to avoid sql injection, simple example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569051/sqlcommand-insert-into-query-does-not-execute

Comment: @J.Pichardo Cause if i don't type ' I will face error

Comment: @VorTex318 That last `'` doesn't have a match, most probably that is causing the error, if not the error may be on the strings you are concatenating, see @Fabio answer, using `SqlParameter` may fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason because you don't using `SqlParameter` for passing values to the query.
If you have used parameters then you will not have such a problem as some extra `'` character in your query.

Always use SqlParameters.

```
public static DataTable InsertConnect(ComboBox Site , ComboBox server , ComboBox Host , ComboBox Domain , Label Price)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Server.Connection))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblPrice(Site,Server,Host,Domain,Price) values (@Site, @Server, @Host, @Domain, @Price)"; 
            var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Site", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Site.text },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Server", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = server.text },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Host", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Host.Text },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Domain", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Domain.Text },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Price", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Price.Text }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use constructor of `SqlDataAdapter` which takes `SqlCommand` as parameter, because your `cmd` contain all needed information for running query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably in one of the parameters which contains an apostrophe ('). Try to print out `cmd.CommandText` and you will see that it is not a valid SQL command.

On a related note, that is the foundation of SQL injection. Solution is not to construct SQL commands by concatenating values, especially strings. Instead, use command parameters and construct parameterized commands.

You can learn more on MSDN: [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)